# How to create C# TCP listner that would keep all clients connected in one thread sending events only when clients write to it?

Tags: c#, .net

Say we want to get API alike this:

```
var Listner = new ServerSocket();
Listner.Bind(URL);
Listner.OnData((senderClient, ClientDataStream) => {/* ... */})
```

- We also want the delegate passed to OnData be executed in limited multythreaded task pool that does not affect socket receiving performance.
- New senderClient tasks shall get into end of task pool only when current task on senderClient was executed.
- Ofcourse while working with OnData we shall be capable of writting data back to clients thrue socket.

We can not provide information on next `ClientDataStream` `length` when parsing current frame. So `ClientDataStream` shall provide abilety to read from it as much as needed in form of async operation alike:

```
{
   byte[] data = ClientDataStream.Read(5).Wait();
   /* */
   byte[] data = ClientDataStream.Read(someDinamicVarNWeGotFromThatFirstFiveBytes).Wait(); //...
}
```

and while task waits it shall probably allow other tasks to work.

Is there such smart socket server in .Net out of the box or in some OSS library?

Comment: Is this a leading question?

Comment: This is a pray for existing base/prototype solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a `ServerSocket` class in .NET. It's just [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx). It can do stuff asynchronously. There is an extensive article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The API is somewhat different from your pseudocode. There is no `OnData` event, but a `BeginReceive` method that takes a callback method.

The `Socket` class does not support async/await out of the box (if you're using .NET 4.5), but I ran into [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) that defines some extension methods for the class to make it possible to use that programming model as well.